# Count number of substrings which contains particular strings

Tags: python, strings

I need to count the number of substrings of `s` which contains both the strings `a` and `b`.

This is what I did till now:

```
a = input().rstrip()
b = input().rstrip()
s = input().rstrip()
min_length = max(len(a), len(b))
n = len(s)
count = 0
for i in range(min_length, n+1):
    for j in range(n+1-i):
        temp = s[j:j+i]
        if (a in temp) and (b in temp):
            count += 1
print(count)
```

The above code works fine, but is slow. How can I optimise it?

**For example:**

**Input:**

```
ab
c
cabc
```

**Output**

```
3
```

Substrings of `s`, which contains both `a` and `b` as substring are `cab` , `abc` and `cabc`.

Comment: You can improve your `min_length` by looking at the non-overlapping length of `a` and `b`, e.g. `len(a) + len(b) - overlap(a, b)` vs just the `max`.

Comment: @AChampion you are right, perhaps I can do `min_length = len(set(a).union(set(b)))`

Comment: While that works for your example it wouldn't work in the general case, this will just be the unique characters, but if `a` or `b` has duplicate characters then it will underestimate. What you need is the `-len(longest_common_substring(a, b))` - you can search on SO for solutions to this.

Comment: okay, got it. Thanks! Any other optimisation?

Comment: substring search in O(n+k) can be achieved by Rabin Karp or Knuth-Morris-Prat.